# What is the best way to change data-ng-attr-X value dynamically in directive?

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

> I have svg *'path'* element with generated **data-ng-attr-d** attribute. Generated attribute value like this:
>
> *data-ng-attr-d*: **M**{{p[0].x}},{{p[0].y}} **L**{{(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).x-p[0].x)}},{{(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).y-p[0].y)}} **L**{{(p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).x-p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).x)}},{{(p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).y-p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).y)}}
>
> *d*: **M**300,100 **L**50,0 **L**150,150
>   [image: First state]

I'm watching points in directive. When adding and deleting point from points array, I'm regenerating path's **data-ng-attr-d** attribute like below:

> *data-ng-attr-d*: **M**{{p[0].x}},{{p[0].y}} **L**{{(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).x-p[0].x)}},{{(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).y-p[0].y)}} **L**{{(p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).x-p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).x)}},{{(p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).y-p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).y)}} **L**{{(p[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E61Q7.png).x-p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).x)}},{{(p[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E61Q7.png).y-p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).y)}}
>
> *d*: **M**300,100 **L**50,0 **L**150,150 **L**-400,-150
>   [image]

Everything looks well yet. But when I move the shape, attributes looks like below:

> *data-ng-attr-d*: **M**{{p[0].x}},{{p[0].y}} **L**{{(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).x-p[0].x)}},{{(p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).y-p[0].y)}} **L**{{(p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).x-p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).x)}},{{(p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).y-p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwLd.png).y)}} **L**{{(p[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E61Q7.png).x-p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).x)}},{{(p[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E61Q7.png).y-p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWsI.png).y)}}
>
> *d*: **M**300,100 **L**50,0 **L**150,150 (LAST POINT -WHICH I ADDED A FEW SECONDS AGO- IS GONE)
>   [image]

I have directive like this:

```
dh.directive('myShape', ['$compile', 'SHAPES', 'shapeService', function ($compile, SHAPES, shapeService) {
return {
    ...,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        shape: '=',
        generateShape: '=',
        shapeIndex: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.shape.index = scope.shapeIndex;
        var elem = scope.generateShape(scope.shape); // returns svg **path** element.
        element.replaceWith($compile(elem)(scope)); // replace **<my-shape>** element with returned **path** element

        //this function is watching points
        scope.$watch('shape.properties.points.length', function () {
            if (shapeService.regenerate[scope.shape.name]) {
                var d = shapeService.regenerate[scope.shape.name](scope.shape);
                if (scope.shape.name == 'polygon' || scope.shape.name == 'polyLine') {
                    elem.setAttribute('data-ng-attr-d', d);
                    $compile(elem)(scope);
                }
            }
        });
    }
...
};
}]);
```

I don't know why this happened. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you may need to post your shapeService

Comment: shapeService is just using to get "data-ng-attr-d"s new value